# Python regex negative extract of an optional group

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have some dates in strings like

```
dates = ['052021','01052021','02112021']
```

Some dates contain the day in between like %m%d%Y and some not, like %m%Y.
I need to be able to extract so that the previous list comes as

```
dates = ['052021','012021','022021']
```

**I can only do it using regex and in one expression**, I have tried something like using the pattern '(\d{2}(?:(\d{2})\d{4})' without any luck.

Comment: You can't extract non contiguous data in a single group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
import regex as re

dates = ['052021','01052021','02112021']
new_dates = [re.sub(r'\B\d\d(\d{4})$', r'\1', s) for s in dates]

print(new_dates)
```

Prints:

```
['052021', '012021', '022021']
```

---

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifD2gJ/1).

- `\B` - Non-word boundary;
- `\d\d` - Two digits (can also use '..' if you want to be less explicit);
- `(\d{4})` - 4 Digits in capture group (can also use '.{4}` again);
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---

**Edit**: With pandas using `str.replace()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['052021','01052021','02112021']})
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'\B\d\d(\d{4})$', r'\1', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    dates
0  052021
1  012021
2  022021
```

Comment: can it be done using capturing groups? (with pandas.str.extract)

Comment: Why can't you use `str.replace()` instead?

Comment: How would you do it with replace?